# Storing string values as constants in the same manner as Enum

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, enums, constants

I know there is a way to make enum work for string types with conversions galore - the code doesn't look pretty.

Does anyone know of any way to have something like this:

```
    public SOMESTRUCTURE SessionKeys : string
{
    value1 = "value1key",
    value2 = "value2key",
    name = "name"
}
```

so later in my code I could refer to it as:

```
SessionKeys.value1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is about the best I've come up with.  (I haven't compiled it, so the syntax may be off.)

```
public static class SessionKeys
{
    public const string Value1 = "Value1";
    public const string Value2 = "Value2";
    ...
}
```

Comment: yeah i was thinking about using the static classes. so much cleaner. Just thought maybe there are some other options out there i wasn't aware of.

Comment: The problem here is that to pass one of these values to a function, you have to use a plain old string parameter, and so of course the compiler would allow _any_ string for that function.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn, gnomixa: You can create your own type, though that is much much messier.  You can also supply a dictionary to validate that it is a valid "SessionKey".  @gnomixa: Also, see this link about your naming: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405851/enum-naming-convention-plural

Answer (score 3):

Using C# 2.0 - I believe the best option is to use a static class with constants for your values, as suggested by [John Fisher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958606/storing-string-values-as-constants-in-the-same-manner-as-enum/958610#958610).

If you can use C# 3.0, you could use a standard enum, and a simple extension method to handle the conversion in a less objectionable manner.

Answer (score 3):

See my answer here:
[Getting static field values of a type using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940002/getting-static-field-values-of-a-type-using-reflection)

The difference between this and John Fisher's answer is that you can pass SessionKeys as function parameters and get the enum-like semantics you want.

The previous question asked for VB.Net, but a C# port shouldn't be that hard.  In fact, here (untested):

```
public interface ICustomEnum<T>
{
    ICustomEnum<T> FromT(T value);
    T Value { get; }

    // Implement using a sealed class with a private constructor 
    // that accepts and sets the Value property, 
    // one shared readonly property for each desired value in the enum,
    // and implicit conversions to and from T.
    // Then see this link to get intellisense support
    // that exactly matches a normal enum:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102084/hidden-features-of-vb-net/102217#102217
    // Note that the completion list only works for VB.
}

/// <completionlist cref="SessionKeys"/>
public sealed SessionKeys: ICustomEnum<string>
{
    private string _value;
    public string Value { get { return _value; } } 

    private SessionKeys(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    private static SessionKeys _value1 = new MyStringEnum("value1key");
    public static SessionKeys value1 { get { return _value1;} } 

    private static MyStringEnum _value2 = new MyStringEnum("value2key");
    public static MyStringEnum value2 { get { return _value2;} } 

    public static ICustomEnum<string> FromString(string value) 
    {
        // use reflection or a dictionary here if you have a lot of values
        switch( value )
        {
            case "value1key":
                return value1;
            case "value2key":
                return value2;
            default:
                return null; //or throw an exception
        }
    }

    public ICustomEnum<string> FromT(string value) 
    {
        return FromString(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator string(SessionKeys item)
    {
        return item.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator SessionKeys(string value)
    {
        return FromString(value);
    }
}
```

You don't *really* need the interface, but I keep it to remind me how to implement them.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that an enum isn't just a static class with a bunch of public numerical constants. An enum is a Type. With constants you lose type safety. You can achieve type safety if you make the static members of your class the same type as the class.

```
public sealed class SessionKey
{
    private _value; 
    private SessionKey( string value )
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public string Value { get return _value; }

    public static readonly SessionKey Value1 = new SessionKey( "Value1" );
    public static readonly SessionKey Value2 = new SessionKey( "Value2" );
}

public class Something
{
    /* stuff */
    public void Foo( SessionKey sessionKey )
    {
        switch( sessionKey.Value )
        {
            case SessionKey.Value1.Value:
                DoBaz();
                break;
            case SessionKey.Value2.Value:
                DoBop();
                break;
            default:
                DoBar();
        }
    }   

    /* other stuff */
}
```