# Class in a class? or something else

Tags: c#, inheritance, switch-statement

I was given this little bit of code by my teacher for this weeks lab to help out and sadly it helps a bit but just not enough. In the context im in "selectedType" i'm not sure about and that's not why i'm here. I'm here because I wanna know if someone can explain what "Airplane.Type.Fighter" could be.
Airplane is a class connected to this one. But i'm not sure if Type is another class that should be inside of Airplane or not.

Thoughts?

```
switch (selectedType)
{
  case Airplane.Type.Fighter:
    newPlane = new FighterJet(name, position, cboPlaneType.SelectedItem);
    break;
  case Airplane.Type.Passenger:
    int numPassengers = Utilities.getIntegerInputValue(txtNumberPassengers);
    newPlane =
    new PassengerAirplane(name, position, txtType.Text, txtFlightNumber.Text, numPassengers);
    break;
  default:
    newPlane = new Airplane(name, position);
    break;
  }
```

Comment: looks like enum to me or const

Comment: It's an inner Enum.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980766/how-do-i-declare-a-nested-enum/980792#980792

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, we can only guess here. My guess is that Airplane is a property of the current class and that `Airplane.Type` is an [enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with values such as `FighterJet` and `Passenger`.

As sean pointed out in the comments, it's a good chance that it's an inner enumeration.

Comment: No, `Airplane` is not a property, it's clearly a class.  But here we see the problems with letting the non-expert asking the question pick the "best" answer.

Comment: It can very well be a property. The only thing indicating it's a class is the `new Airplane` part, but the property can very well be named Airplane.

Comment: No, it cannot be a property. If it were, it wouldn't work in the case statement.

Comment: Yep, you're actually right. Missed that one. You shouldn't be on SO this late :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Airplane
{
    public enum Type
    {
        Fighter,
        Passenger
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's probably an [`enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the definitions of Airplane here, to get an answer.
This information is insufficient for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a Class.Enum.EnumType or it can be Class.Class.Const

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to find out if you look at the definition of the `Airplane` class. Also, the type of `selectedType` should give you an indication. If you don't have the source code, Visual Studio can generate a class outline for you if you right click on `Airplane.Type.Passenger` (for example) and choose "Go To Definition". Also, you can use a tool like [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) to look at the code.

But, it seems it's a nested enum (the most obvious choice):

```
class Airplane {
  public enum Type {
    Fighter,
    Passenger
  }
}
```

But it can also be a nested type with constants:

```
class Airplane {
  public static class Type {
    public const string Fighter = "Fighter";
    public const string Passenger = "Passenger";
  }
}
```