# how to create or emulate nested enums

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

I am trying to create a nested enum in flutter/dart. it will serve as a structure to use as keys in certain maps holding their values. something like this :

```
enum Settings{
  WIFI_SETTINGS,
  UI_SETTINGS,
  STORAGE_SETTING {
    FTP_SETTINGS {
      HOST,
      PORT,
      KEY
    },
    DB_SETTING {
      TYPE,
      HOST,
      PORT,
      UNAME,
      PWD
    }
  }
}
```

then to be able to use it like this

```
Map AllSettings = Map<Settings,dynamic>();

print(AllSettings[Settings.WIFI_SETTINGS]);
print(AllSettings[Settings.STORAGE_SETTING.FTP_SETTINGS.PORT]);
```

Clearly the above code is not acceptable within dart, is there anyway of achieving this ?

Comment: You can draw inspiration from that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980766/how-do-i-declare-a-nested-enum

Comment: Would `AllSettings[Settings.STORAGE_SETTING.FTP_SETTINGS.PORT]` really be much better than `AllSettings[Settings.STORAGE_SETTING_FTP_SETTINGS_PORT]`?

Comment: Trying your code in an editor seems to start giving issues when you embed { inside the enum since it is expecting } to end the enum. Nested classses, string keys (i.e. `AllSettings["storage.ftp.port"]`), or nested Maps (`AllSettings[Settings.STORAGE][StorageSettings.FTP][FTPSettings.PORT]` might also work