# Split long enum into smaller groups or namespaces

Tags: c#, enums

I'm currently dealing with a long enum with roughly 100+ elements, where the first word in each element is used to categorize the entries:

```
public enum UserPermissions{
    FilesRead,
    FilesWrite,
    FoldersRead,
    FoldersWrite,
    NotesCreate,
    NotesDelete,
    NotesModify,
    ...
    ...
}
```

I would like to categorize the permissions into a more organized structure using namespaces such as:

```
UserPermissions.Files.Read;
UserPermissions.Notes.Modify;
```

The main issue here is to maintain compatibility with existing code by avoiding or minimizing refactoring needed. What is the best solution?

My current idea is to convert the enum to a class:

```
public class UserPermissions
{
    public enum Files{
        Read  = 1,
        Write = 2,
    }

    public enum Folders
    {
        Read  = 3,
        Write = 4,
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

But this will require refactoring old code such as `UserPermissions.FilesRead` to `UserPermissions.Files.Read`.

Comment: So you want to move it to a new structure without having to change anything? That's pretty much impossible. You're going to have to refactor something.

Comment: You want to leave old code untouched and only make new code use namespaced structure?

Comment: Why don't you use namespaces? Create UserPermissions namespace and all enum definitions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you realy do not want to refactor, you can provide both temporarly:

```
public enum UserPermissions{
    FilesRead,
    FilesWrite,
    FoldersRead,
    FoldersWrite,
    NotesCreate,
    NotesDelete,
    NotesModify,
}

public class UserPermission //Other name then enum, or the class must be under a different namespace
{
    public enum Files
    {
        Read  = UserPermissions.FilesRead,
        Write = UserPermissions.FilesWrite,
    }

    public enum Folders
    {
        Read  = UserPermissions.FoldersRead,
        Write = UserPermissions.FoldersWrite,
    }
}
```

If you now have a method, you could simple cast `(Folders)userPermission`.

But **you shouldn't do this**. It's error prone (casting) and not according to DRY (Don't repeat your self). You should start refactoring instead.

Simple write your new enums, compile, fix, compile, fix, compile [...] -> success.

Comment: i think this is the best solution for my situation as it provides a temporary solution until the code can be properly refactored later

Comment: BTW, you only want to make enums that represents flags in plural. Every other should be singular. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1405874/2441442) @Tee

Comment: Thanks for tip, I'll refactor that as well

Answer (score 0):

if you use one of them to save it to a database you should maintain the same number you had on your legacy code, otherwise you will run in trouble, changing the structure should not affect the behavior of your code, but you will need to refactor everything, so far that is the cost I am seeing here